# React / Stripe / injectStripe HOC / "stripe.createToken is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

The task is to create a test Stripe implementation. All it needs to do is take the standard test input (4242...) and return a non-failure response. I've managed to get most of the way through this, but am stumped by how to implement the HOC injectStripe piece. The end result is that the code returns a "stripe.getToken() is not a function" error, and I can't figure out how to get around this error.

My guess is that the answer is simple / obvious, however I am completely new to this and don't know what this answer is, yet.

I don't know what to do, to fix this. Some help / guidance is needed. Thank you for your time and attention.

**Here is some code:**

paymentInfo.js

```
export default function PaymentInfo(stripe) {
    const handleFinishOrder = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
    
        const { token } = await stripe.createToken() // <<< here is the error

        async function fetchStripe() {
            // API fetch that needs token
        }

        fetchStripe();
    }
        
    function handlers() {
        return {
            handleFinishOrder: handleFinishOrder       
        }
    }

    return (
        <StripeProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}>
            <Elements>
                <PaymentInfoDisplay handlers={handlers()} /> // <<< see next code sample
            </Elements>
        </StripeProvider>        
    )
}
```

PaymentInfoDisplay.js

```
const PaymentInfoDisplay = ( props ) => {
    const { handleFinishOrder } = props.handlers

    return (
        // A simple <form/> with Stripe elements for card number, exp. date, etc.
    )
} 

export default injectStripe(PaymentInfoDisplay)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that you're attempting to use the `stripe` prop *inside* of the function where you invoke the `<StripeProvider />` component. You should instead make the `createToken()` call in a child component in the tree (even in your `PaymentInfoDisplay` component). Below is a (truncated) example:

```js
export default function PaymentInfo(stripe) {
  return (
    <StripeProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}>
      <Elements>
        <PaymentInfoDisplay />
      </Elements>
    </StripeProvider>        
  )
}
```

```js
const PaymentInfoDisplay = (props) => {
  const { stripe } = props

  const handleClick = () => stripe.createToken()

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
} 

export default injectStripe(PaymentInfoDisplay)
```

However this HOC integration is generally deprecated and no longer recommended. Instead you should refactor your code to use the [`useStripe` hook](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react).

Comment: That helps clarify the issue, as well as helps solve it. 

Also, thanks for the tip about the useStripe hook!